# Trouble adding Python to Path

Tags: python, installation

I've followed the tutorial and I still can't get Python to run in the command prompt and hence can't get it to run in Sublime Text 3.

I seem to have the right address.

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Each directory should have its own entry. Instead, you have them all in one string. To create a new entry, press the new button and put in one directory.

It should look similar to this:

[image]